# Responsive image slider using picture element?

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

Does anyone know of an open source code or snippet example of a responsive image slider with <   > navigation controls that uses picture element when resized? I've tried repurposing so many free ones and nothing seems a good reliable fit. I would prefer it be pure css but I can work with JavaScript if need be.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Adam.

Comment: Have you tried Slick http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Just recommended [FlexSlider](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/) to someone else yesterday.

Comment: Can u use it without Wordpress?

Comment: Yes you can use it without wordporess

Answer (score 1):

Slick Carousel will do the job...

http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

In regards to using the picture element here is an example...

HTML

```
<div class="your-class">
  <picture>
     <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  </picture>
  <picture>
     <img src="http://placehold.it/351x151">
  </picture>
  <picture>
     <img src="http://placehold.it/352x152">
  </picture>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.your-class').slick({
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
    });
});
```

**JsFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/kennethcss/u0b9dx8a/

**Available for WordPress here...**

http://maxgalleria.com/downloads/slick-slider-for-wordpress/

Unfortunately, the WordPress version is not open source :(

Comment: Slick actually does not work with the picture element when multiple sources are defined (which is really the only reason to use the picture element).

Answer (score 0):

You can use below free sliders. My favorite is Owl Carousel.

Swiper-
https://swiperjs.com/

Owl Carousel-
https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/

Slick-
https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/